# Forecasting future occurrences with Random Forest

Tags: python, time-series, random-forest, forecasting

I'm currently exploring the use of Random Forests to predict future values of occurrences (my ARIMA model gave me really bad forecasting so I'm trying to evaluate other options). I'm fully aware that the bad results might be due to the fact that I don't have a lot of data and the quality isn't the greatest. My initial data consisted simply of the number of occurrences per date. I then added separate columns representing the day, month, year, day of the week (which was later one-hot encoded) and then I also added two columns with lagged values (one of them with the value observed in the day before and another with the value observed two days before). The final data is like this:

```
Count   Year    Month   Day Count-1 Count-2 Friday  Monday  Saturday Sunday Thursday Tuesday Wednesday
196.0   2017.0  7.0    10.0 196.0   196.0     0       1        0       0       0     0        0
264.0   2017.0  7.0    11.0 196.0   196.0     0       0        0       0       0     1        0
274.0   2017.0  7.0    12.0 264.0   196.0     0       0        0       0       0     0        1
286.0   2017.0  7.0    13.0 274.0   264.0     0       0        0       0       1     0        0
502.0   2017.0  7.0    14.0 286.0   274.0     1       0        0       0       0     0        0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I then trained a random forest making the count the label (what I'm trying to predict) and all the rest the features. I also made 70/30 train/test split. Trained it on the train data and then used the test set to evaluate the model (code below):

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 42)
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels)

predictions = rf.predict(test_features)
```

The results I obtained were pretty good: MAE=1.71 and Accuracy of 89.84%.

First question: is there any possibility that I'm crazily overfitting the data? I just want to make sure I'm not making some big mistake that's giving me better results than I should get.

Second question: with the model trained, how do I use RF to predict future values? My goal was to give weekly forecasts for the number occurrences but I'm kind of stuck on how to do that.

If some who's a bit better and more experienced than me at this could help, I'd be very much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adressing your first question, random forest might tend to overfit, but that should be checked when comparing the MAE, MSE, RMSE of your test set. What do you mean with accuracy? Your R square? However, the way to work with models is to usually make them overfit at first, so you have a decent accuracy/mse/rmse and later perform regularization techniques to deal with this overfitting by setting a high `min_child_weight` or low `max_depth`, a high `n_estimators` is also good.

Secondly, to use your model to predict future values, you need to use the exact same model you trained, with the dataset you want to make your prediction on. Of course the features that were given in train must match the inputs that will be given when doing the forecasting. Furthermore, keep in mind that as time passes, this new information will be very valuable to improve your model by adding this new information to your `train` dataset.

```
forecasting = rf.predict(dataset_to_be_forecasted)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have one question though: to forecast the data, what exactly to I pass to the model? I know that in ARIMA (and other variants) you can simply define the amount of time steps you want to forecast into the future and it gives you the results. Here what am I exactly feeding to the model? Because if I want to predict next week's occurrences, I won't have, for example, the lagged variables for all the days. I hope the question is clear

Comment: Yes I understand, this could lead to a whole post, a few pages long. The model is way more simple than an ARIMA imo. There are many issues, first as you describe there is no direct option in a random forest to lag or forward the model. You are feeding all this numerical data (columns) so that the trees split into n-dimensions so that the information gain, or the accuracy is best. I've answered to help you with your questions. However, I would not suggest using a random forrest for a time-series analysis. How about you check LSTM networks? Cheers!

Comment: Currently, instead of using lagged variables of 1 and 2 days, I'm trying to use 1 week and 2 weeks. This way I could then feed the model new data where I would have the desired dates to forecast and the values from a week and two weeks before (Does this sound reasonable)?. LSTM are probably a bad option here as I don't have a lot of data.... In fact, I only have full one year with data from jan to dec, and then a few months of 2017 and 2019. But thanks for your input!