# What is my dataframe's x value when using sklearn RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm working on a big data project for my school project. My dataset looks like this: https://github.com/gindeleo/climate/blob/master/GlobalTemperatures.csv

I'm trying to predict the next values of "LandAverageTemperature".

I've asked another question about this topic earlier.(its here:[How to predict correctly in sklearn RandomForestRegressor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460378/how-to-predict-correctly-in-sklearn-randomforestregressor)) I couldn't get any answer for that question.After not getting anything in my first question and then failing for another day, I've decided to start from scratch.

Right now, I want to know which value is in my dataset is "x" to make the prediction correctly. I read that y is a dependent variable which that I want to predict and x is the independent variable that I should use as "predictor" to help the prediction proccess. In that case my y variable is "LandAverageTemperature". I don't know what the x value  is. I was using date values for x at first but I'm not sure that is true at the moment.

And if I shouldn't use RandomForestRegressor or sklearn (I've started with spark to this project) for this dataset please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one variable (`LandAverageTemperature`), so obviously that's what you're going to use. What you're looking for is the `df.shift()` function, which shifts your values. With this function, you'll be able to add columns of past values to your `dataframe`. You will then be able to use `t 1 month/day ago`, `t 2 months/days ago`, etc, as predictors of another day/month's temperature.

You can use it like this:

```py
for i in range(1, 15):
    df.loc[:, 'T–%s'%i] = df.loc[:, 'LandAverageTemperature'].shift(i)
```

Your columns will then be `temperature`, and temperature at `T-1`, `T-2`, for up to 14 time periods.

For your question about what is a proper model for time series forecasting, it would be off-topic for this site, but many resources exist on https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question might sound stupid but I don't know much about regression itself. So, its obvious that I should use "T" value for x, but I have 15 of them. In this case, if I want to use `RandomForestRegressor` for my model, which T value should I use? Can I use multiple predictors? If so, how?

Comment: I think some basic tutorials might help you, there are plenty. In short, you will need to separate your `y` and `x`. Then, you will use the `model.fit(x, y)` method, and then `model.predict()` on your test set. There are tutorials in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)

Answer (score 1):

In general case you can use for X feature matrix **all data columns excluding your target column**. But in your case there is several complications:

- You have **missed (empty) data** in most of the columns for many years. You can exclude such rows/years from train data. Or exclude columns with missed data (which will be almost all of your columns and it's not good).
- Regression model can't use date fields directly, you should traislate date field to some numerical field(s), "months past first observation", for example. Something like **(year-1750)*12 + month**. Or/and you can have year and month in separate columns (it's better if you have some "seasonality" in your data).
- You have sequental time data here, so may be you should not use simple regression. Use some ARIMA/SARIMA/SARIMAX and so on so-called **Time-Series** models which predicts target data sequentially one value by another, month after month in your case. It's a hard topic for learning, but you should definitely take a look at TS because you will need it some time in the future if not today.